# Umlauts in iPhone v-card

Tags: c#, encode, vcf-vcard

I need to send e-mails to iPhone users with .vcf files for adding contacts. The problem is that contact name has umlaut symbols and they displays incorrectly. 
Also I noticed that if I send the same text in the body of email or open composed vcf file in notepad the symbols displays correctly.

```
public void SendEmail(string to, string subject, string body)
    {
        using (var message = new MailMessage())
        {
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            message.HeadersEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body)))
            {
                string attachamentName = string.Format("{0}.vcf", subject);
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(stream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet) { Name = attachamentName };
                attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;
                message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

                using (var client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    client.Send(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: incorrect v-card]

[image: the same text in the body]

Can someone please help me?

**UPDATE**: Sorry, have to edit code sample, I've accidentally submit the wrong one.

**UPDATE #2**: It looks like it is not only iPhone problem, Outlook also does not recognize umlauts.

**UPDATE #3**: Added full code for sending e-mail

Comment: Send emails _to_ iPhone users, from what platform?

Comment: can you post an example of the attachment body?

Comment: It is displayed in the second screenshot. I just put the content of the file to e-mail body.
"BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:2.1\r\nN:Fältskog;Agnetha\r\nFN:Agnetha Fältskog\r\nORG:\r\nTITLE:\r\nEND:VCARD"

Comment: ah, sorry, images are broken for me - probably corp proxy issue

Comment: What we need here is the full email that is being sent. You may miss some content-type parameter etc...

Comment: I've updated the question with full code for sending e-mail. Yes, I don't have a content-type but how should I add it?

Comment: related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287505/cncontact-encoding-of-properties

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to:

```
BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:2.1\r\nN;CHARSET=LATIN1:Fältskog;Agnetha\r\nFN;CHARSET=LATIN1:Agnetha Fältskog\r\nORG:\r\nTITLE:\r\nEND:VCARD
```

Just from reading elsewhere - looks like the format needs this `CHARSET` tag on each field, and seems that either `LATIN1` or `iso-8859-1` character sets, rather than `utf-8` need to be specified for these.

Comment: unfortunately, neither of this charsets are working, still incorrect symbols in contact

Comment: @ChrisBallard I don't see why you could not go with UTF-8 instead of Latin1. `Ä` **is** part of unicode: `U+00C4`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
VERSION:2.1\r\n
```

to

```
VERSION:3.0\r\n
```

After that you don't need [CHARSET-Tags for fields with umlauts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287505/cncontact-encoding-of-properties),
it should work as expected.