# CNContact encoding of properties

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

I have a v-card string with the first name `André` and I initialise a `CNContact` with the v-card.

```
BEGIN:VCARD

VERSION:2.1

N:Foo;André;;;

FN:André Foo

TEL;CELL:00023 4474848

END:VCARD
```

I initialise the contact with the raw string like this:

```
if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        let contacts = try CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: data)
        let contact = contacts.first
        return contact

    } catch {
        print("Data is not a VCard")
    }
}
```

But when I print out the raw string of `contact.givenName` I get:

`Andr√©`

How can I get the proper string of the Contacts framework in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a charset to the vcard fields, it defaults to ASCII.

```
BEGIN:VCARD

VERSION:2.1

N;CHARSET=UTF-8:Foo;André;;;

FN;CHARSET=UTF-8:André Foo

TEL;CELL:00023 4474848

END:VCARD
```

If you want to hack around this specific type of error in the vcard then you can inject the charset manually into it:

```
let fixed = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\nN:", with: "\nN;CHARSET=UTF-8:").replacingOccurrences(of: "\nFN:", with: "\nFN;CHARSET=UTF-8:")
```

Comment: But what If I can't control the charset? Let's assume I get the vcard from a third party...

Comment: Then the third party needs to fix their vcards.

Comment: This is not useful at all, sorry. If the web was like that, we all should give up right now...

Comment: In some cases it is not possible (fix third parties) due to hardware restriction rules. For example, storing vCard data onto NDEF records, written on NFC-tag. It is too expensive fill each field with messy CHARSET=UTF-8 substring.

Comment: So why do we need `;CHARSET=UTF-8` on each item? Cant we add it globally? I tested this on an iphone device but it could not read the qr code. Do you have a better (more compact) global solution?

Comment: So I found the solution: It only works per-property, except with vcard4, which is utf8 by default: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/106901